# Regex to capture after a certain number of slashes in folder url

Tags: regex, url, matching

Can someone provide me with the regex to capture only a certain part of the folder location after 5 forward slash?

i.e. M:\Information\Folder1\Folder2\Folder 3\Folder A\Example.pdf

I want to capture all of the string before the 5th slash (Before Folder A).

Regards,

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I'm hopeless with regex. I know basic regex but usually I go by cheat sheets on regexr.com - they don't have any advice of finding after counting a certain number of the same symbol.. I think it's much more advanced for my level @Utkanos

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why 
it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time 
to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, 
and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! 
See also: [ask]

Comment: Which language is it for?

Comment: @ThomasAyoub Thanks for the advice, It's not for any language. It's for a software called FME which allows you to search attributes based on a regex command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do:

```
^(?:[^\\]*\\){4}[^\\]*
```

- `^(?:[^\\]*\\){4}` matches first 4 `\`s including the substring before them
- `[^\\]*` matches the substring before the 5th `\`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GdbCgj/9)

Comment: Thanks @heemayl - out of curiosity what does the ? do.

Comment: @user1568128 `?:` creates a non-capturing group. As we don't need to capture the match, hence we're using the non-capturing group.